# amplifyjs decoders and ajax beforeSend

Tags: jquery, amplifyjs

Alright, working on getting amplify decoders. Strange issue. If I have a beforeSend attached to my request, the decoder does not fire. remove the beforeSend and the decoder fires.

Here are the two examples.

1. With no beforeSend.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/Td2P4/12/

1. With beforeSend

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/Td2P4/14/

Can someone tell me what is happening? why wouldnt the decoder work if I have a beforeSend? I am assuming the decoder should fire after the request is received, so beforeSend should not have any impact on it!

note: stackoverflow wants me to post code here, not just fiddles

//please check the fiddles

```
amplify.request({
    resourceId: "testRequest",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            text: 'hello world'
        })
    },
    success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(data, status);
        $('.messages').append('<div> text retrieved: ' + data.text + '</div>');
    },
    error: function(status, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});​
```

Help?

-Suj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

in amplifyjs this section caught my eye

```
beforeSend : function( _xhr, _ajaxSettings ) {

                xhr = _xhr;
                ajaxSettings = _ajaxSettings;
                var ret = defnSettings.beforeSend ?
                    defnSettings.beforeSend.call( this, ampXHR, ajaxSettings ) : true;
                return ret && amplify.publish( "request.before.ajax",
                    defnSettings, settings, ajaxSettings, ampXHR );
            }
        });
```

note that, it will call beforeSend if it is specified, else set `var ret` is set to `true`

if set to true, it will then publish `"request.before.ajax"`

way down in the file, amplify listens for this message

```
amplify.subscribe( "request.before.ajax", function( resource, settings, ajaxSettings, ampXHR ) {
var _success = ampXHR.success,
    _error = ampXHR.error,
    decoder = $.isFunction( resource.decoder )
        ? resource.decoder
        : resource.decoder in amplify.request.decoders
            ? amplify.request.decoders[ resource.decoder ]
            : amplify.request.decoders._default;

if ( !decoder ) {
    return;
}

function success( data, status ) {
    _success( data, status );
}
function error( data, status ) {
    _error( data, status );
}
ampXHR.success = function( data, status ) {
    decoder( data, status, ampXHR, success, error );
};
ampXHR.error = function( data, status ) {
    decoder( data, status, ampXHR, success, error );
};
```

});

so, if you have a beforeSend and if it does not return true, the message is never published and the decoders are never hit!

the solution?

return true from your beforeSend function

```
amplify.request.define("testRequest", "ajax", {

url: "/echo/json/",
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
decoder: function(data, status, xhr, success, error) {
    console.log('decoder fired');
    $('.messages').append('<div>decoder fired </div>');
    success(data);
},
beforeSend: function(xhr){
//not doing anything here, just logging;
    console.log('before send fired');
    $('.messages').append('<div>before send fired </div>');
    return true; //this is the key
}
```

});

works like a charm! Hope this helps someone else trying to figure this out!

Comment: This did help me out, thanks. In my case, I was trying to define a custom cache, ran into this same issue. Couldn't find any documentation covering this. Appreciate your posting your research!

Answer (score 0):

Just copied this from the example pages. Hope it helps.

```
amplify.request.decoders.appEnvelope =
    function ( data, status, xhr, success, error ) {
        if ( data.status === "success" ) {
            success( data.data );
        } else if ( data.status === "fail" || data.status === "error" ) {
            error( data.message, data.status );
        } else {
            error( data.message , "fatal" );
        }
    };

amplify.request.define( "decoderExample", "ajax", {
    url: "/myAjaxUrl",
    type: "POST",
    decoder: "appEnvelope" // <--- a function name(string) and not a function.
});

amplify.request({
    resourceId: "decoderExample",
    success: function( data ) {
        data.foo; // bar
    },
    error: function( message, level ) {
        alert( "always handle errors with alerts." );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan for that response. my stuff is also from their docs and as I said, it all works great except when there is a beforeSend in the request. that is where it does not fire the decoder. So no, your response does not help. :(